# Where in the world are encrypted software in cash registers required and in that case what security measures are required?

Tags: encryption, embedded, standards-compliance, system

**Background**

Sweden is transitioning to a compulsory law for all business owners handling cash or card transactions, to implement/buy partially-encrypted POS (point of sale)/cash registers:

> Signing and encryption are used to
>   securely store the information from
>   the cash register in the control unit.
>   The control system with a certified
>   control unit is based on the
>   manufacturer for each control unit
>   model obtaining a main encryption key
>   from the Swedish Tax Agency. The
>   manufacturer then uses the main key to
>   create unique encryption keys that are
>   placed in the control unit during the
>   manufacturing process. In order to
>   obtain main encryption keys,
>   manufacturers must submit an
>   application to the Swedish Tax Agency.
>   [Source SKV](http://www.skatteverket.se/fordigsomar/startadrivaforetag/kassaregister/newcashregisterlegislationbecomeseffective1january2010.4.69ef368911e1304a6258000272.html)

This has caused somewhat of an uproar among Swedish traders because of the necessitated complexity and strong encryption to be used, along with a highly sophisticated technical implementation from the shop owner's perspective, as the alternative is to buy the system from companies who have traversed the documentation, gotten their security keys and built the software and integrated it into the hardware.

**So my first question is if any other countries in the world even comes close to the preciseness that the Swedish Tax Agency requires of its companies (alongside having extensive guidelines for bookkeeping)?**

I'd like to hear about any other encryption schemes of interest and how they are applied through legislation when it comes to verifying the transactions and book keeping entries. Examples of such legislation could be similar to another Swedish rule; that book keeping entries (transactions) must be write-only, at most written 4 days after the occurrance and only changeable through a tuple of (date, signature of person doing it, new bookings).

**Finally, what are your opinions on these rules? Are we going towards all-time uplinks for book keeping + POS systems to the tax agency's servers which verify and detect fraudulent patterns in real-time similar to the collective intelligence algorithms out there or will there be a back-lash against the increased complexity of running business?**

Comment: I can't see a programming question here. And even if there were one as you are polling for opinions, this should be Community Wiki.

Comment: I made it a community wiki. It is a question highly relevant to programming though, and generally what it's like living as a programmer in today's world.

Comment: I work with POS software, I say it's programming related.

Comment: I work with POS software, too... Oh, you mean "Point of Sale" - nevermind.

Comment: What type of fraud from merchant this can prevent? Can someone provide an example for Cash POS?

Comment: Since everything that is registered in the system is also sent to the control box where it is encrypted, the control sums make it hard for the merchant to use "phantom software" that deletes transactions throughout the day; at least he can't without the sums failing to match up. It's quite common that merchants in the food-business don't register purchases or register them as the wrong good. I don't know if this answers your question.

Comment: An example for a fraudulent cash purchase might be a transaction that is made but not entered into the "official" transaction record.  The company collects sales tax or VAT from the customer, but instead of turning the tax over to the government keeps it for themselves.  This is on the same lines as paying an employee in cash "off the books" to avoid having to pay income tax on their wages.

Comment: You might also want to ask this at serverfault.com... for an IT perspective on things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Offhand, I can't think of anywhere else in the world that implements this strict of a requirement.  However, some existing POS systems may implement this sort of encryption depending on what the definition of "control unit" is and where the differentiation between "control unit" and "cash register" lies.

The reason I say this is because many POS systems (at least the ones that I've worked with) are essentially a bunch of dumb terminals that are networked to a central database and transaction processing server.  No data is actually stored in the cash register itself, so there is only a need to encrypt it on the server side (and over the wire, but I'm assuming a secure network protocol is being used).  You would need to get a lawyer to interpret what exactly constitutes a "control unit", but if this can be defined as something on the server side (in a networked POS case like this) then the necessary complexity to implement such a system would not be too onerous.

The difficult case would be where each individual cash register requires a unique encryption key, whether to encrypt data to be stored inside the register itself or to encrypt data before sending it to a central server.  This would require a modification or replacement of each cash register, which could indeed prove costly depending on the size of the business and the age of the existing equipment.  In many countries (the US in particular), mandating such an extensive and costly change would likely have to be either accompanied by a bill providing funds to businesses (to help pay for the equipment conversion) or written in a manner more like "all Point-Of-Sale equipment manufactured or sold after {{{some future date}}} must implement the following features:".  Implementing rules that place expensive burdens on businesses is a good way for politicians to lose a lot of support, so it's not likely that a rule like this will get implemented over a short period of time without some kind of assistance being offered.

The possibly interesting case would be the "old-fashioned" style of cash registers which essentially consist of a cash drawer, calculator, and receipt printer and store no data whatsoever.  This law may require such systems to start recording transaction information (ask your lawyer).  Related would be the case where transactions are rung up by hand, written on a paper ticket (like is commonly done in some restaurants and small stores in the US).  I often find it amusing how legislation focuses on such security for high-tech systems but leaves the "analog" systems unchanged and wide open for problems.  Then again, Sweden may not be using older systems like this anymore.

I'm not sure exactly what US law requires in terms of encrypted records, but I do know that certain levels of security are required by many non-government entities.  For example, if a business wants to accept credit card payments, then the credit card company will require them to follow certain security and encryption guidelines when handling and submitting credit card payment information.  This is in part dictated by the local rules of legal liability.  If a transaction record gets tampered with, lost, or hijacked by a third party the security of the transaction and record-keeping systems will be investigated.  If the business did not make a reasonable effort to keep the data secure and verified, then the business may be held at fault (or possibly the equipment manufacturer) for the security breach which can lead to large losses through lawsuits.  Because of this, companies tend to voluntarily secure their systems in order to reduce the incidence of security breaches and to limit their legal liability should such a breach happen.

Since device manufacturers can sell their equipment internationally, equipment complying with these Swedish restrictions will likely end up being used in other places as well over time.  If the system ends up being successful, other businesses will probably volunteer to use such an encrypted system, even in the absence of legislation forcing them to do so.  I compare it to the RoHS rules that the EU passed several years ago.  Many countries that did not sign the RoHS legislation now manufacture and use RoHS-certified materials, not because of a legal mandate but because they are available.

**Edit:** I just read this in the linked article:

> Certified control unit
>
> A certified control unit must be
>   connected to a cash register. The
>   control unit must read registrations
>   made by the cash register.

To me, this sounds like the certified control unit attaches to the register but is not necessarily connected to it (or necessarily unique to a register).  This definition alone doesn't (to my non-lawyer ears) sound like it prohibits existing cash registers from being connected over a network to a certified control unit on the server side.  If so, this might be as simple as installing some additional software (and possibly a peripheral device) on the server side.  The details link may clarify this, but it's not in English so I'm not sure what it says.

Answer (score 0):

These types of requirements are becoming more and more common across most of Europe (and to a lesser, but increasing, extent North America). I'm not sure exactly which Europe-based banks are moving fastest on this, but in North America one of the front-runners is First Data (who have already made available the fully-encrypted POS devices like you describe needing).

I would further postulate that most merchants will not develop systems internally that do this (due to the PCI requirements, and challenges in doing so), but will instead rely on their merchant providers for the required technology.